# How to peacefully remove space station

Tags: stellaris

My borders recently expanded and I managed to take control of the system of another empire. I need to build an observation station on a planet but the other empire already built one.

I can disband a mining station, but the option is not available for an observation post.

How can I remove the current space station and build my own?

Comment: Is the system in a sector?

Comment: @RavenDreamer it is in a sector owned by me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the observation post actually still belongs to the other empire. Ownership of these is not transferred when system control changes. No idea, whether it's a bug or intentional.

The only option is to go to war again and destroy the observation post.

Comment: Well that seems like a serious problem. That observation post can take control of the planet, giving the system back to the original owner.

Comment: Not sure when it changed, but this seems to have shifted in a subsequent patch. Observation posts now change hands, I think (and, interestingly, you inherit the old owner's policy - I aquired an ob post and almost immediately afterwards had it complete technological enlightenment... a bit of a surprise!)

Comment: Yes, this behavior seemed to have changed at some point in the last 2.5 years because I just inherited an observation outpost when I took a bunch of nearby systems.